# Alternative to using sed inside loop

Tags: sed

I want to replace multiple (non-consecutive) lines of a big file, using files that contain one single line. What I found to work is

```
for i in ${list[@]}; do
   line=$(cat file_$i.txt);
   sed -i "$i c $line" bigfile.txt;
done
```

Here, `list` contains the lines I want to replace. Here is an example:

```
$ list=(1 3 4 7)
$ cat file_1.txt
this is the new line 1
$ cat file_3.txt
this is the new line 3
$ cat file_4.txt
this is the new line 4
$ cat file_7.txt
this is the new line 7

$ cat bigfile.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
```

The output of the above script is

```
$ cat bigfile.txt 
newline 1
line 2
newline 3
newline 4
line 5
line 6
newline 7
line 8
```

It works, but in every step of the loop `sed` opens and reads the whole file, as I understand it, so this method is very slow. What are the other faster ways to do this, preferably using `sed`?

Comment: Side note, don't use backticks for command substitution; use `$(` and `)` instead, which is more readable and can be easily nested.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to fathom what you want to do, can you clarify? Let shellcheck.net make corrections to your script too.

Comment: I have a big file of data from simulations, in which each simulation corresponds to one line, but some of them stopped early, so I ran them again. Now I want to replace their lines with the new data in the corresponding lines without doing so manually.

I will edit the post, but I think the downvotes were unnecessary.

Comment: @RenanNobuyukiHirayama, the downvotes are necessary if _This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear** or not useful_. Besides, your script inserts all `line`s before the last line of `bigfile.txt`, so where is this "correct position" you are talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
sed "$(for i in $list; do echo "$i c $(cat file_$i.txt)"; done)" bigfile.txt
```

(`$list` could have to be `${list[@]}` or `${list[*]}` or anything else, depending how it is constructed.)

Your original loop is used to build a Sed script each line of which is like `1 c content_of_file_1_dot_txt`; this script is then run only once on `bigfile.txt`.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I only had to change ```$list``` to ```${list[@]}``` (I'm still not completely comfortable with bash arrays).

Comment: Wow, that's nesting! +1. May the reader bear in mind that this is guaranteed to work with GNU sed, but not POSIX sed.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the `list[]` array and run this in a directory containing just your files:

```
awk '
sub(/^file_/,"",FILENAME) { map[FILENAME+0] = $0; next }
{ print (FNR in map ? map[FNR] : $0) }
' file_*.txt bigfile.txt
```

or if you're set on using a list[] array too:

```
awk -v list="${list[*]}" '
BEGIN {
    split(list,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        lineNrs[tmp[i]]
    }
}
NR in lineNrs {
    if ( (getline line < ("file_" NR ".txt")) > 0 ) {
        $0 = line
    }
    close("file_" NR ".txt")
}
{ print }
' bigfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
<<<"${list[@]}" sed -E 's/\S+/&r file_&.txt\n&d\n/g' | sed -i -f - bigfile
```

Or using GNU parallel:

```
parallel 'echo "{}r file_{}.txt";echo "{}d"' ::: ${list[@]} | sed -i -f - bigfile
```

Or if the replacement text files only contain one line each:

```
parallel echo '{}c$(<file_{}.txt)' ::: ${list[@]} | sed -i -f - bigfile
```

Or you might prefer to use the file names in the current directory:

```
parallel --rpl '{@} s/[^0-9]//g' 'echo "{@}r {}";echo "{@}d"' ::: file_* |
sed -i -f - bigfile
```